# Facebook apprequest Link"wrong"

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, request

Im using this Docu and Script to send an app request to some friends.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'apprequests',
    message: 'My message',
    max_recipients: 3
}, requestCallback);
```

Its working fine but if they click the Link in the FB notification bar they dont get linked directly to my page and app. Instead they are at a "step between". The app is visible in an iframe with less than 810px and no like button (so the design is broken and the like gate cant be deactivated.

This are the link parameters:

```
/?fb_source=notification&request_ids=1234567890&ref=notif&app_request_type=user_to_user&notif_t=app_request
```

Where is the problem? Why is FB not linking the user to the app in page directly?

I guess the solution is somewhere in the App settings maybe... but i dont know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Citing Requests documentation:

> Accepting a request will direct the user to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

That is, once user accept request he will be landed to your application canvas (which is 720 pixels wide).

[image: Application Settings screenshot]

This is desired behavior and there are additional arguments passed to Canvas URL to provide details about request.

- `fb_source` -  indicate where user accepted request from
- `request_ids` - provide comma separated ids of requests user is accepting

Once user landing to your application by accepting request you are free do issue additional redirection to the desired page.

Comment: thanks.. i used the GET parameter 'fb_source' to redirect from the "stupid" 720px page directly to facebook.com/page/app

Answer (score 3):

Check out your app Settings:

- Go to: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ click on you app, and then on edit.
- Click on advanced on the left
- Check if you app is not in sandbox mode
- Check out the canvas settings